# Regular expression to match a word while preserving end of line

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I have a string as follow:

```
str = 'chem biochem chem chemi hem achem abcchemde chem\n asd chem\n'
```

I want to replace the word "chem" with "chemistry" while preserving the end of line character ('\n'). I also want the regex not match words like 'biochem', 'chemi', 'hem', 'achem' and 'abcchemde'. How can I do this?

Here's what I'm using but it doesn't work:

```
import re    
re.sub(r'[ ^c|c]hem[$ ]', r' chemistry ', str)
```

Thank you

Comment: So what are your expected matches?

Comment: Why not just `\bchem\b`?

Comment: 'chem' at the beginning, 'chem' in the middle and 'chem\n' at the end of the lines. I may note that the '\n' characters should be preserved after replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. Thanks to @Jota.

The super-simple Regex is as follow:

```
re.sub(r'\bchem\b', r' chemistry ', str)
```

Comment: you should not have spaces around `chemistry` since `\b` does not actually capture the whitespace

Comment: But ' chemistry ' is just the replacement string. What does it have to do with \b?

Comment: if you replace `'chem'` with `' chemistry '` you will have extra spaces around each replacemen

Comment: Oh right. I'm doing it doing it on purpose. But thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5):

use word boundaries:

```
>>> s = 'chem biochem chem chemi hem achem abcchemde chem\n asd chem\n'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bchem\b','chemistry',s)
'chemistry biochem chemistry chemi hem achem abcchemde chemistry\n asd chemistry\n'
```

just a note, dont use `str` as a variable name, that covers the builtin `str` type

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `\b` to match a word boundary:

```
import re    
re.sub(r'\bchem\b', r'chemistry', mystring)
```

(And as R Nar pointed out, you should avoid using `str` as a variable name.)